# Access crash reports Xcode 6.3.1 from Apple Review process (iOS)

Tags: xcode

I have just spent 6 months developing my first iOS app. It runs perfectly on simulators and devices.

When I submitted it to for Apple review, I got a message back "crashed when loading". The resolution centre provided three crash reports (pointers to web pages). I can view these in a browser.

But they do not appear in the "crashes" section of Organiser (which says "no crash reports"). I cannot see how to open these reports in Xcode to symbolicate them - I have tried dragging and dropping them into both Organizer and Devices (they can't be dragged and dropped anywhere in these windows), converting them to text files with .crash extensions, about a million things with no luck.

Does anybody know how I "import" crash reports into Organizer so I can symbolicate them? Or why they don't appear automatically in the Crashes section of Organizer?

Tearing my hair out. Any assistance gratefully welcomed.

Comment: I too would like to know this information as my own game is currently under review.

Comment: I think you can ask directly your problem to the resolution center.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't believe it is possible to symbolicate app approval crashes through XCode. But somebody provided me with this excellent little symbolicator:

https://github.com/agentsim/Symbolicator

Just drag a crash report onto the Dock icon and Symbolicator will spit out a .symbolicated file in the same directory as the source file.

Works a treat, it found where my program crashed, simple fix.

Recommended